# Streaming data with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, streaming, httpurlconnection

I want to use HttpURLConnection to open a long-living connection to a server via HTTP POST and process streaming data as it comes in.  This is for an Android project.

It's unclear to me how to do this with HttpURLConnection.  In iOS, NSURLConnection provides an asynchronous mode where a user-implemented callback gets called as new data comes in and is available for parsing.

With the HttpURLConnection in Java, I see there's an available() method that returns the number of bytes that can be read.  But, its unclear how I would write a streaming app that opens a connection and reacts as new streaming data becomes available to parse off a DataInputStream.

I would appreciate some input.  Does HttpURLConnection or an alternate class in Java support non-blocking, asynchronous processing of HTTP connections?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing more research, I've confirmed that Java doesn't have any built-in support for asynchronous HTTP.  A packaged called Jetty contains a HTTP client with built-in asynchronous HTTP and callbacks.  Its available at:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/HttpClient

Answer (score 1):

Create an Object that extends `Observable` and implements `Runnable`. Your main application implements `Observer` and adds itself to your new object as an observer.

Run your object in a new thread. It does blocking reads on your HTTPUrlConneciton and notifies observers with the data that has just been read.

Answer (score 1):

> there's an available() method that
>   returns the number of bytes that can
>   be read

No there isn't. There is an available() method that returns the number of bytes that can be read *without blocking.* Not at all the same thing.

HttpURLConnection doesn't sound like a good fit for this task. HTTP is a request-response protocol, not a streaming protocol, at least as implemented in the Java classes.

Comment: Read up on comet and you'll see there are many large-scale projects that use the long-living HTTP connection approach... iOS natively supports non-blocking HTTP connections.  The standard Java classes apparently never envisioned this as a possibility (being older).